# JQueryMobile: simple url doesn't render properly after loading

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Situation: got a list of links which should load another list (located at the same server).

Problem: After clicking a link the content is being rendered as plain html.

Demo: http://covraag.nl/derma/index.html

Question: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just a note that jQueryMobile is still in alpha.  It may not be you.

Comment: Strange thing is that it works on their own demo. Somehow the urls become abc.html#a.html instead of just a.html

Comment: Wanted to help, but your demo is not loading at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't post a direct answer to your problem as the example is unavaliable, but here are some mistakes that could be easily made:

- bad doctype or no doctype
- invalid html
- no wrapping HTML at all - jquery loads it with ajax, but expects a proper page
- typo in data-roles
- duplicated IDs on page
- missing data-role

[edit]

Everything looks ok at first glance. Only thing you do wrong is adding stuff in the head of the [letter].html - this is ignored when the site is fetched by the link. Try making the head section look the same in all html files. But I don't think this is why it doesn't work. I just bring it up, because it will create problems later.

Your problem is all in the head [Do I sound like Yoda? ;)]
 1. your index has jqm 1.0a1 instead of a2 linked
 2. **there are some issues with jqm and jquery 1.4.4 that cause your kind of problems. Switch to jquery 1.4.3** - I tested, it works then

Comment: Thanks Naugtur! I fixed the demo url, could you take another look?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time, patience and the bug fix! You've saved me a lot of time/headaches :)

Comment: @naugtur, Is there any link(s) you can post for further reading about that jq 1.4.4 issue? I was under the impression that jqmobile alpha2 required jq 1.4.4 (http://jquerymobile.com/2010/11/jquery-mobile-alpha-2-released/)

Comment: @electblake here is where I remember it from: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/issue/477#issue/477/comment/545439